# Pgfplots: Assemble dates from different columns

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot a datafile of a time series in pgfplots. The date is not in the `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm` format required by the PGF calendar library (see p. 210 in the [pgfplots manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf)), but in different columns called `year`, `month`, `day` etc.

Is there a way of joining different columns into a new string in the required format on the fly when calling `\addplot table` (maybe with something like `x expr=...`)? I'm trying to avoid using `\pgfplotstableread` with a `create on use` command because I have found that to take surprisingly long to run.

Here's an example of the datafile format I'm talking about:

```
year, month, day, hour, minute, value  
2006, 5, 21, 1, 0, 10.5  
2006, 5, 22, 2, 0, 23.4  
2006, 5, 22, 4, 5, 30.1  
2006, 5, 27, 3, 0, 35.2
```

Comment: You can always use `create on use` with a `pgfplotstableset` command *after* you use `pgfplotstableread`.

Comment: can be done with `pst-plot`. When using `xelatex` you can create directly a pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am aware that this question is quite old now... but in case there is still interest in an answer: here is one which works "on-the-fly":

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
```

```
\pgfplotsset{
    custom date format/.code={
        % set the normal data format:
        \pgfkeysalso{date coordinates in=x}%
        % query the 'x coord trafo' key's value:
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/x coord trafo/.@cmd}\temp
        % store it (globally):
        \global\let\theolddatacoordtrafo=\temp
        % redefine it:
        \pgfkeysdef{/pgfplots/x coord trafo}{%
            % evaluate the expression:
            \edef\temp{#1}%
            \message{Coordinate \coordindex: Using \temp.^^J}%
            % now, insert the *value* of '\temp' as argument to
            % the original 'x coord trafo':
            \expandafter\theolddatacoordtrafo\temp\pgfeov
        }%
    },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    custom date format={\thisrow{year}-\thisrow{month}-\thisrow{day} \thisrow{hour}:\thisrow{minute}}, 
    % pretty-printing:
    width=\linewidth,
    xticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=near xticklabel},
    xticklabel=\day. \hour:\minute,
]
\addplot table[col sep=comma,y=value] {
```

year, month, day, hour, minute, value
2006, 5, 21, 1, 0, 10.5
2006, 5, 22, 2, 0, 23.4
2006, 5, 22, 4, 5, 30.1
2006, 5, 27, 3, 0, 35.2
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

My idea here was to define a custom 'x coord trafo', which concatenates your columns in a "proper" way and then hands the concatenated and expanded ('\edef' = expanded definition) result to the 'x coord trafo' which is used by the dateplot lib.

Consequently, the dataplot lib is unaware of the preprocessing step and the preprocessing step is performed on-the-fly.

Actually, the feature to assemble symbolic coordinates from tables is missing in pgfplots. I have taken a note on my todo list such that future versions will (eventually) support something like the 'x symbolic expr={\thisrow{year}-\thisrow{month}...}'.

Comment: Oh wow, this is very impressive! Works like a charm! Thanks for answering the question even though it's quite old, the solution is definitely still useful to me! (And thanks for `pgfplots`, by the way. Such a useful tool!)

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any way to do this with pgfplots without using the `create on use` command, as this is exactly what the command is for. Your speed issue may be related to timing: it may be much faster to import the data one time using `\pgfplotstableread`, and then use `pgfplotstableset` to create custom columns, or to use the `read completely` command to put the entire file into memory before any post or pre processing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that my datafile is just too large to be handled gracefully by `pgfplotstables` (3000 rows with 15 columns): Reading the table first using `\pgfplotstableread` is still unusably slow. But you're right, `create on use` seems to be the only way to do stuff like that.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend a preprocess step to the input file. With Linux, the following command on a terminal

```
awk --field-separator="," '{printf "%d-%d-%d %d:%d %e\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' input_file > output_file
```

results in an output_file with the format

```
2006-5-21 1:0 1.050000e+01
2006-5-22 2:0 2.340000e+01
2006-5-22 4:5 3.010000e+01
2006-5-27 3:0 3.520000e+01
```

etc., which should be usable with the `pgfplots` package in reasonable time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's a very elegant way of doing it. Note that the separator between the date/time and the number should be something other than a whitespace (a comma, for example), because the date and time need to be in the same field for `pgfplots` to use it. The pattern could thus be something like `"%d-%d-%d %d:%d,%e\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be complicated to do in Latex, if I were you I would preprocess the data. Tools like Excel( use the concatenate function ) or R ( use the paste function ) are helpfull and you have it done in two minutes.

Unless its absolutely necessary to that directly in Latex ofc...