# How to make a pgfplots stacked xbar plot with bar-"explicit meta" labels computed from input table data

Tags: pgfplots, nodes, labels, bar-chart

I am making a pgfplots stacked xbar plot where each bar has a distinct
label, in addition to a numeric bar length.  Each pair of bars also
has a common label.  I would like to mark each bar with its distinct
label and its length, and mark each pair of bars with their common
label.

Two parts to my question (EDIT: (1) is answered in [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7246/pgfplots-assemble-dates-from-different-columns)):

1. how to avoid defining the extra `Score-name` column (see MWE
    below), and instead compute it from the `Score` and `Name`
    columns in the table? EDIT: according to the package author
    (answer to [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7246/pgfplots-assemble-dates-from-different-columns)), there is no built-in support for this, but
    it's on his TODO list. EDIT 2013-3-25: according to [answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103813/13043), this is now supported.
2. how to make the computed labels appear on the right y axis,
    instead of at the end of the bars?

I don't know the best way to depict the data, but *per bar* `extra y
tick` labels, as in Jake's answer to [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42919/how-to-make-an-xbar-plot-with-pgfplots-having-different-y-tick-labels-on-the-l) would
probably be good.

I couldn't figure out how to get *per bar* `extra y tick` labels,
but I have alternate solution where the label placement is not as
good: add an extra column to the input data table and use it for the
per-bar labels.  Problems with this solution include: having to add
the extra column; not being able to use the pgfplots command to format
the numeric part of the labels from the extra column (illustrated
below); and (subjectively) that it doesn't look as good as `extra u
tick` labels would.

My MWE (also based on Jake's answer to [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42919/how-to-make-an-xbar-plot-with-pgfplots-having-different-y-tick-labels-on-the-l).  Thanks Jake!) has two
figures.  The first figure shows my solution by manually adding the
`Score-name` column, and the second figure shows how the numeric
formatting directives (i.e. scientific notation) are not being honored
in that first figure (which seems natural, because `Score-name` is
not numeric).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data1.dat}
Age-interval  Y-Position  Score   Name  Score-name
20-30         1           0.15    Peter {0.15 (Peter)}
30-40         2           0.20    Jeff  {0.20 (Jeff)}
40-50         3           0.12    Steve {0.12 (Steve)}
50-60         4           1.24    John  {0.24 (John)}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data2.dat}
Age-interval  Y-Position  Score    Name    Score-name
20-30         1           0.159    Peeteer {0.159 (Peeteer)}
30-40         2           0.209    Jeeff   {0.209 (Jeeff)}
40-50         3           0.129    Steevee {0.129 (Steevee)}
50-60         4           1.249    Joohn   {0.249 (Joohn)}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={The \texttt{format/sci} is ignored below, but the \texttt{font=\textbackslash{}small} is obeyed below:},
    xbar,     
    %bar width=2pt,
    ytick=data,
    width=8 cm,
    height=6 cm,
    enlarge y limits={true, value=0.2},
    xmin=-0.01,
    xmax = 2.0,
    xticklabel pos = upper,
    tick align = outside,
    yticklabel pos=left, 
    yticklabels from table={data.dat}{Age-interval},
    %ylabel={Age intervals (yr)},
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={
      anchor=west,
      font=\small,
      % This format/sci gets ignored, because the Score-name is not a
      % number:
      /pgf/number format/sci,
      %/pgf/number format/zerofill,
      /pgf/number format/precision=2,
    },
    point meta=explicit symbolic
]
\addplot table [
    y=Y-Position,
    x=Score,
    meta=Score-name
] {data1.dat};
\addplot table [
    y=Y-Position,
    x=Score,
    meta=Score-name
] {data2.dat};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Both the \texttt{format/sci} and the \texttt{font=\textbackslash{}small} are obeyed below:},
    xbar,     
    %bar width=2pt,
    ytick=data,
    width=8 cm,
    height=6 cm,
    enlarge y limits={true, value=0.2},
    xmin=-0.01,
    xmax = 2.0,
    xticklabel pos = upper,
    tick align = outside,
    yticklabel pos=left, 
    yticklabels from table={data.dat}{Age-interval},
    %ylabel={Age intervals (yr)},
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={
      anchor=west,
      font=\small,
      % This format/sci gets ignored, because the Score-name is not a
      % number:
      /pgf/number format/sci,
      %/pgf/number format/zerofill,
      /pgf/number format/precision=2,
    },
    % THIS IS UNCOMMENTED ABOVE
    %point meta=explicit symbolic
]
\addplot table [
    y=Y-Position,
    x=Score,
    meta=Score-name
] {data1.dat};
\addplot table [
    y=Y-Position,
    x=Score,
    meta=Score-name
] {data2.dat};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: My solution]
[image: Illustration of problems]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a custom hack which is tailored only to the problem at hand. First we redefine the `nodes near coords*` for our own purposes and removing many of the necessary checks. Because we are sure that we won't be using them. **You have to take it inside the TikZ picture environment to make this local to the picture otherwise all pictures will be affected.**

Then, when placing the nodes near coords we fix the bounding box of the local scope with a coordinate, named `(O)` here. Then we reset the transformation inside that scope locally. This allows us to compute the distance to the right `y`-axis and we `west` anchor the node with a little shift to the left.

Regarding the first question you can use `visualization depends on=` key to harvest data from other tables, format the number printing etc.

There might be an easier way to do the positioning but I just made it on auto pilot. Please use this to show smarter ways of doing it.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{filecontents}{data1.dat}
Age-interval  Y-Position  Score   Name  
20-30         1           0.15    Peter
30-40         2           0.20    Jeff  
40-50         3           0.12    Steve
50-60         4           1.24    John  
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data2.dat}
Age-interval  Y-Position  Score    Name    
20-30         1           0.159    Peeteer 
30-40         2           0.209    Jeeff   
40-50         3           0.129    Steevee 
50-60         4           1.249    Joohn   
\end{filecontents}

\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/nodes near coords*/.append style={scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
       \begin{scope}
         \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
         \pgftransformreset
         \path let \p1 = ($(axis description cs:1,1)-(O)$) in
          node[/pgfplots/every node near coord,anchor=west] at ([xshift=\x1+1.5mm]O) {#1};
       \end{scope}
       }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar,clip=false,     
    ytick=data,
    width=8 cm,height=6 cm,
    enlarge y limits={true, value=0.2},
    xmin=-0.01,xmax = 2.0,
    xticklabel pos = upper,
    tick align = outside,
    yticklabel pos=left, 
    yticklabels from table={data2.dat}{Age-interval},
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Name} \as \labela},
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{Score} \as \labelb},
    every node near coord/.append style={
      font=\small,
    },
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[sci]{\labelb} (\labela)},
]
\addplot table [
    y=Y-Position,
    x=Score,
] {data1.dat};
\addplot table [
    y=Y-Position,
    x=Score,
] {data2.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]