# pgfplots - How can I achieve an xbar plot with bars adding up to 100% on both ends?

Tags: pgfplots, legend

**edit** I don't need a solution anymore, I decided to not use the "negative" bars on the right side but I am leaving (and not deleting) this question in case someone else is looking for this in the future.

I'd like to produce this xbar plot style, where the two values obivously add up to the full 100%.

[image]

I already found a question named [How to make a pgfplots stacked xbar plot with bar-“explicit meta” labels computed from input table data](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52767/how-to-make-a-pgfplots-stacked-xbar-plot-with-bar-explicit-meta-labels-compute), but as far as I understood things it does not really help.

**note** Please do edit the title if you have a better phrase in mind for this question. I'm not a native speaker and couldn't think of a better description.

**MWE** of what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{
pgfplots,
relsize,
sansmath
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small\sansmath]
\begin{axis}[
height=7cm,
width=14cm,
%
xmin=0,
xmax=100,
%
ymin=2006,
ymax=2011,
%
xbar,
%
%axis lines*=left,
%
scaled y ticks=false,
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}},
%
xlabel={Something in \%},
ylabel={Years},
%
legend style={at={(0.8,1.25)}},
legend columns=2,
legend cell align=left,
%
enlarge x limits=0.05,
enlarge y limits=0.1,
every axis x label/.style={
at={(ticklabel* cs:0.5)},
anchor=north,
yshift=-10pt
},
every axis y label/.style={
at={(ticklabel* cs:1.02)},
anchor=south,
text width=3cm
},
]
\addplot
[draw=black,fill=black!60]
coordinates
{(82.8,2011) (81.7,2010) (79.3,2009) (70.3,2008) (65.4,2007) (63.8,2006)};
\addlegendentry{abc}
\addplot
[draw=black,fill=white]
coordinates
{(17.2,2011) (18.3,2010) (20.7,2009) (29.7,2008) (34.6,2007) (36.7,2006)};
\addlegendentry{def}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Picture** of what I have so far:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stack bars by using `xbar stacked` instead of `xbar`. If you use a table to provide the data, you can furthermore calculate the "negative" bar automatically:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotstableread{
Year Value
2006 63.8
2007 65.4
2008 70.3
2009 79.3
2010 81.7
2011 82.8
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0,
xmax=100,
%
ymin=2006,
ymax=2011,
%
xbar stacked,
%
scaled y ticks=false,
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}},
ytick=data,
%
xlabel={Something in \%},
ylabel={Years},
enlarge y limits={abs=0.5},
%
nodes near coords,
every node near coord/.append style={anchor=east}
]
\addplot
[draw=black,fill=black!60, every node near coord/.append style=white]
table [x=Value, y=Year] {\datatable};
\addplot
[draw=black,fill=white, point meta=explicit]
table [x expr=100-\thisrow{Value}-1e-5, y=Year, meta expr=100-\thisrow{Value}-1e-5] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's very clever!